# How to delete all rows from table which has no FK relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I have a table that its primary key used in multiple tables.

I want to delete the rows that have no relation FK in other tables.

How to delete all rows from table which has no FK relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can select like this:

```
select * from some_table where some_fk_column not in (
  select some_column from second_table
)
```

if you get good result,then

```
delete from some_table where some_fk_column not in (
  select some_column from second_table
)
```

Comment: This could also suffer from the cascading deletes issue. Without checking _all_ other tables for references _before_ deleting a row it is possible that a cascading delete will be triggered. If cascading deletes are disabled then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do all without checking all other related tables I say a way but you should take care while using it:

1. loop through your table
2. delete the record, if any FK is exists then the record will not
   delete (use `TRY/CATCH` blocks)

in this way you do not need to check all fk and tables

**Notice:** this way assumes that cascade delete is disabled.

```
Select *
Into   #Tmp
From   YOUR_TABLE

Declare @Id int

While EXISTS(SELECT * From #Tmp)
Begin

    Select Top 1 @Id = Id From #Tmp

    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

    Delete FROM #Tmp Where Id = @Id

End
```

Comment: Do you suppose cascading deletes might surprise the OP? They may not be enabled, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: @HABO you are right, I forgot to mention it, answer edited. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but it should work:

```
select   m.ID
from     mastertable m
where    not exists( select 1 from table1 where fk_id = m.ID )
    and  not exists( select 1 from table2 where fk_id = m.ID )
    and  not exists( select 1 from table3 where fk_id = m.ID )
    and  not exists( select 1 from table4 where fk_id = m.ID )
    and  so on;
```

You will do a table scan of the master table (you want to check every row) but as soon as any reference is found in any of the other tables, those scans halt and the master id is rejected. If the FK column in each of the others tables are indexed, those will be seeks. Anything that makes it all the way through is an ID value that is not referenced in any of the tables.

Now just feed the query above to a `delete` statement and you get rid of all unreferenced rows.